# Swipe to Delete React Component not React Native

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js, react-swipeable-list

I've a problem.
I want implement the swipe to delete in my webapp in react.
I tried react swipeable, i tried Swiper but these not solve my problem. How I create the function with drag to right the Item and show right background color, with text: DELETE ITEM? I want that work, when I drag the ItemContainer.
In add, I want represent the informazion of ItemContainter with DELETE ITEM.

Help me please.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the code for what you have tried?

Comment: I found this from a google search: https://codesandbox.io/s/swipe-to-delete-component-and-cutom-function-forked-uu1upo

Comment: I have React 18. This library not work with my app @dmikester1

Comment: I want clean the code, I've function HandleDelete for API OPERATION, but I want solve this problem of the drag

Comment: Its hard to offer up much help without seeing some code of what you have tried.